# AWS get-cost-and-usage by resource Tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to get the costs for my aws resources by environment or usage.
I setup my environments such that all resources (rds instances, vpc endpoints, ecs clusters and tasks etc etc) have a tag `Environment: test` or `Environment: prod`.

Now I want to explore the costs using aws cli:

```
aws ce get-cost-and-usage --time-period Start=2022-03-01,End=2022-04-09 --granularity MONTHLY --metrics "BlendedCost" "UnblendedCost" "UsageQuantity"   --filter file://costfilter.json
```

with `costfilter.json':

```
{
  "And": [
    {
      "Dimensions": {
        "Key": "REGION",
        "Values": ["us-east-2, eu-central-1"]
      }
    },
    {
      "Tags": {
        "Key": "Environment",
        "Values": ["test"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I get no errors so syntactically it is fine, however it shows

```
DimensionValueAttributes: []
ResultsByTime:
- Estimated: false
  Groups: []
  TimePeriod:
    End: '2022-04-01'
    Start: '2022-03-01'
  Total:
    BlendedCost:
      Amount: '0'
      Unit: USD
    UnblendedCost:
      Amount: '0'
      Unit: USD
    UsageQuantity:
      Amount: '0'
      Unit: N/A
- Estimated: true
  Groups: []
  TimePeriod:
    End: '2022-04-09'
    Start: '2022-04-01'
  Total:
    BlendedCost:
      Amount: '0'
      Unit: USD
    UnblendedCost:
      Amount: '0'
      Unit: USD
    UsageQuantity:
      Amount: '0'
      Unit: N/A
```

Unfortunately the truth is that it is not all 0, so something is wrong here.

Is this the correct way to achieve what I want? If so what is missing? If not, how then do I approach it ?

ps. for instance `alb elbv2 describe-tags` for a certain lb will give me:

```
TagDescriptions:
- ResourceArn: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:640753244498:loadbalancer/app/mosar-lb-test/3d7bd13953ee06b8
  Tags:
  - Key: Environment
    Value: test
  - Key: ManagedBy
    Value: ecs-cluster
```

So the tags really do exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did send the regions within your dimensions wrong:

```
"Values": ["us-east-2, eu-central-1"]
```

should be

```
"Values": ["us-east-2", "eu-central-1"]
```

Please also note, that the "current" date will often be 0, because of calculation of AWS itself. This is why we request in our cost monitoring tool all costs from a date in the past to "yesterday", to be sure, to have the full costs of the days.

To filter by tags, you also have those tags as "cost allocation tags", see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html

Comment: Thx! The first part was actually very obvious, the second less. However, it is still not working unfortunately. I updated my post showing examples of the tags. Are there "different types of tags" or something ? I Still get zeros.

Comment: It could be (this is what I do not know at the moment) you have to add your tags also as "cost allocation tags", see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html

Comment: Thanks I will try that. It seems to be necessary, judging by the docs. I just enabled the tags, now I do not see anything yet, but I am not sure if it also works for costs made in the past. Will keep on looking !

Comment: Yes that was it, today I see some costs coming up for yesterday. Thanks for your help.